# Unable to reverse each word in array in Ruby ( Without built-in function reverse)

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, function, loops

I am trying to reverse each word in an array and here is what I have tried. I am unable to figure out why this code of array `(word.size-1..0)` won't give me any results in the new arr[].
Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
words  = ["hello", "world", "programmer", "ama", 'abc']
def reverse_words words
  arr = []
  words.each do |word|
    (word.size-1..0).each do |alphabet|
      arr << word[alphabet]
    end
  end
  arr
end
```

Comment: Try `words.map(&:reverse) #=> ["olleh", "dlrow", "remmargorp", "ama", "cba"]`, which is shorthand for `words.map { |word| word.reverse }`.  See [String#reverse](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-reverse). Whenever you give an example please show the desired result.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland, thanks for your comment but I do not want to use the built-in function (reverse).

Comment: If you are constrained to not use a particular approach, it would be best to specify that in your question.

Comment: @Chris the question is updated. Thanks for telling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a range with start value higher than end value and Ruby treats it as empty array, for example:

```rb
(5..0).to_a
=> []
```

In this example Ruby can't find number that is higher than `5` and lower than `0`, so it returns an empty array.

You can try following code to iterate from higher to lower number:

```rb
(5).downto(0).each do |number|
  ...
end
```

Comment: `:downto` accepts a block, so you can just write: `5.downto(0) do |number| ... end`